# How can I get a notification when someone edits a pipeline definition?

Tags: azure-devops

As part of our change control process I need to get notified anytime someone edits a pipeline or release definition. I couldn't find a way to create a subscription for this type of notification. I can view the history, but also need to get notified when a new entry is added. Is this possible?

Comment: if you use yml, you can add yourself as a review when someone tries to edit it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#automatically-include-code-reviewers

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I'm assuming you are using Classic Pipelines, as opposed to YAML Pipelines.  In that case I don't think you can do this out of the box.

If you were using YAML Pipelines then you can configure notifications on changes to the file in the repo or set a reviewer policy for the file in the repo.  History is then handled in the same way as history for any other file.  Two good reasons to migrate ;)

Comment: I guess there are two parts I am looking at - I have yaml defintion for the pipeline execution steps which I can view/edit from devops and are stored in our repo.  Then I also have the release definitions that show a workflow-like view of my artifacts and stages (which has a history tab).   Changes to either of these can impact what is generated and deployed to my service.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get a notification when someone edits a pipeline definition?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid Azure devops does not support this way/feature to sent notification when someone edits a pipeline definition at this moment.

Even if our pipeline type is yaml, we cannot set notifications when someone changes the pipeline. Because the subscription can only be limited to a specific folder, and not to a specific file yaml, unless we put the yaml in a specific file, we can set notifications for it:

[image]

Besides, personally think that your request is reasonable. You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.